# Leaving '08 Civic sitting for a few months

Tags: honda, starting, civic

Quick question: I have a 2008 Honda Civic. It has been sitting for almost 4 months now, and there will be no chance to drive it for another month or so, making it 5 months in total. I believe the oil was at an okay level, along with the gas when it was left. What type of problems should I expect? Should I bring a mechanic with me when I go to start it up for the first time again? I am completely incompetent when it comes to cars so I will likely need someone else to do any immediate work on the vehicle, should it be required.

Comment: Try this [link](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/125/reviving-a-vehicle-that-has-been-idle-for-a-long-time) and/or [this](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/269/starting-a-car-that-has-been-sitting-for-about-a-year)

Comment: Check out this thread , addresses all of your needs, http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/125/reviving-a-vehicle-that-has-been-idle-for-a-long-time?lq=1