# Keep car in best condition which is not regularly used

Tags: damage

I often commute to my work using bicycle and public transport, and groceries and family visits are also done via bicycle and public transport. As a result, my car - Hyundai Matrix petrol car - is not used regularly. Sometimes the car is not used for up to two months.

Still I want to have a car, for holidays and the times public transport is not an option. A car [can deteriorate](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18148/what-damage-does-a-car-suffer-if-not-regularly-used) if it is not frequently used.

This time when I used the car, I actually noticed I had to use extra throttle  (once) to get the car moving, as if something was stuck.

How can I keep my car in the best condition, in both maintenance and usage terms? Do I frequently need to check the oil levels, and drive it once a few weeks?

Comment: The "something was stuck" is probably the brakes. The surface of a brake disk rusts over when a car's parked. After a few weeks, there's enough rust that the brake pads are stuck to the disk. This resolves itself when you drive off.