# Fresh battery, no lights on 1979 Honda CB125

Tags: honda, motorcycle, battery, wiring

I have a 1979 Honda CB125 that was running consistently about 2 years ago. It then sat for two years and the battery was corroded so I replaced it. I've made sure the battery is charged (I have a charger). I also replaced one of the ring terminals on my bike.

I'm getting no lights and it won't start (it's a kick start.)

Is something up with my wiring?

Where should I look next?

Comment: Have you had any luck resolving this issue?  I believe there will be more things you'll need to resolve after the electrical power component like bad fuel in the carb, clogged carb, flushing fuel system, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reviving a vehicle that has been idle for a long time.](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/125/reviving-a-vehicle-that-has-been-idle-for-a-long-time)